# Can't Access CI object in thread class using pthreads

Tags: multithreading, codeigniter, pthreads

Can't get instance of CI Object to use model in run() function of thread class.

Thread is starting ok but not able to call model functions Please help !!!

```
class Clinical extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('directory');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set("max_execution_time", '0');
        ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
        $dirList = scandir('../clinicalTrial/');
        $data["dirList"] = $dirList;
        $this->load->view('clinical',$data);
    }

    public function import()
    {
        $folder = $_POST["folder_name"];
        $dir = directory_map('../clinicalTrial/'.$folder);
        $key = $folder;
        $myThreadObj = new ClinicalThread($dir,$key);
        var_dump($myThreadObj->start());
        echo "Import Done";
        exit;
    }
}

class ClinicalThread extends Thread
{
    public $dir = array();
    public $key = "";

    public function __construct($dir,$key)
    {
        $this->dir=$dir;
        $this->key=$key;
    }

    function run()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        echo "";
        print_r($CI);
        exit;
        if(!empty($this->dir))
        {
            foreach($this->dir as $file)
            {
                $CI->ct->extract($this->key,$file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is my first question..i might not have asked correctly..if u have solution for this then please comment..how i can use model in thread run() function while calling thread start() function.

Comment: no offense - this wasn't meant as an insult, rather as an information - because if you read this carefully you stumble upon the section _Help others reproduce the problem_ which contains _Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem_ and refers to this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - simple said pls show your code because nobody - absolute nobody - can solve your problem without sight to the code ...

Comment: thanks for your response. I have edited code can you please check now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call Model function of the framework inside thread, as It doesn't load the framework engine inside the thread.

Please use direct DB connection inside the thread to communicate with the Database.